# Chance post id into post name

Tags: post-meta

I´d like to echo the post name instead post id. My code shows just the id.

```
<?php 
global $post;
$customlink = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clink', true ); 
echo $customlink;
?>
```

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this meta field store some other post's ID, of which you want to retrieve the post name?

If so, try this

```
<?php 
global $post;
$customlink = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clink', true );

echo get_post_field( 'post_name', $customlink );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
global $post;
echo $post->post_title;
// or even better
echo apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title);
?>
```

Like that?